# CSS Animation/transition interacting with opacity

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, opacity

At the moment, I have some text fading in and out, and when the user hovers over the text, it should 'transition' to its full opacity (opacity: 1).

Currently, I have this: `https://jsfiddle.net/17ppzb2p/4/

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div id="start">
        START
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInOut{
    0% {
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes glow {
    0% {
        opacity: 0.4;  /*from current opacity*/
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
#start {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 80px;
    font-size: 36px;
    letter-spacing: 30px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-animation: fadeInOut 6s infinite;
    /* -webkit-transition: opacity 1s; */
    /* Failed attempt to use transition to change opcaity. */
}
#start:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -webkit-animation: glow 2s;
    /* opacity: 1; */
}
```

I want the opacity to go from the current opacity controlled by the fadeInOut animation --> to full opacity.

I know that in order to use the current value of opacity that I should use 'transition', but when I try this, it does not overwrite the current opacity from the fadeInOut animation.

I hope this made sense :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the opacity to 0 for #start (before hover).  Whenever you're using transition, you need to make sure you have a "initial" setting.

```
#start {
  opacity: 0 //here
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 80px;
  font-size: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 30px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
}

#start:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

This should work. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: Keep in mind that when dealing with opacity on text, it might be better to use color: rgba(0,0,0,0) and color: rgba(0,0,0,1.0) and then do the transition on color instead.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work :( Here's my real code that I ran it against: https://jsfiddle.net/ccr1ca8s/ Instead, your solution just freezes the opacity when hovered. Would you mind having another look, please? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full opacity effect on hover text you can set initial opacity as you want. For example:

`#start {  opacity: 0.3 //here  position: absolute;  top: 50px; left: 80px;
  font-size: 36px;  letter-spacing: 30px;  color: black;  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;} #start:hover {  opacity: 1; }`

and on hover set it to 1.

Comment: Exactly what plushyObject said... It doesn't work, sorry.